# Execute event only if a treeview node is clicked

Tags: delphi, treeview

I, (more time), trying to execute action when i click into a item of a treeview see:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if treeview1.Selected.AbsoluteIndex=1 then
  begin
    showmessage('selecionado');
  end; 

end;
```

This code show a message if user click into index 1 of a treeview, The problem is the following: If the user selects the index 1, the message will be shown, however after that, the user click into empty area of the listview the message is still performed because the item is still selected. How can I make the event run only if the User clicks the corresponding item?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `OnClick`, which occurs whenever the `TTreeView` is clicked (not only when a node is clicked). Instead, use the [`TTreeView.OnChange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnChange) event, which passes you the node:

```
procedure TForm3.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if Assigned(Node) then
    if Node.AbsoluteIndex = 1 then
      ShowMessage('selecionado');
end;
```

Comment: In addition, one has to think of the keyboard. Some people only use the keyboard, and no mouse.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I wanted to use the event "TTreeView.OnChange". But it doesnt fire by click or key presses. Do you have any idea, why it doesnt fire the event ?

Comment: Any solution in case someone wants to use the treeview's OnClick event handler instead of OnChange?

Comment: @tdiop: Read the first sentence of my answer, which answers the question in your comment. If you want to handle a click anywhere on the TreeView, use `OnClick`. If you want to handle clicks on individual nodes (and not on areas that don't have nodes), use `OnChange`. That is quite clearly explained in my answer.

Comment: OnChange fires only once but what if I want to handle consequtive click on the same item?

Comment: @Anton: Then handle both OnChange and OnClick, checking the selected node in the OnClick handler when it fires to see if it's the same one you just handled in OnChange.

Comment: @Ken It would not work if the second click is on empty space

Comment: @Anton: Then it wouldn't be *consecutive click on the same item*, right? Make up your mind what you want. :-)

Comment: @Ken what i really want is to toggle imageindex between 0 and 1 on each click on node but not on click on empty space

Comment: @Anton: If you have a question, you need to create a new question, not ask about it in comments to a 2+ year old question belonging to someone else. Regarding what you wrote, you can do that exactly as I said in my first comment to you above. Set the imageindex wherever you want it in OnChange, and then in OnClick see if it was the same node and toggle the imageindex.

Answer (score 4):

```
procedure TfClerks.tvHqClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  with tvHq.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos) do
    Node := tvHq.GetNodeAt(X, Y);
  if Node = nil then
    Exit;
  // do something
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected) then
    begin
        if SameText(TreeView1.Selected.Text, 'show form1') then
            ShowMessage('selecionado')
        else
           if SameText(TreeView1.Selected.Text, 'show form2') then
               ShowMessage('s22');
    end
end;
```